# Object property change in bound ObservableCollection doesn't change UI values

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a UWP-app in C# that can control my lights in my home. I am able to fetch the data from the server and create lamp objects for each individual lamp. These lamp objects are then place in an `ObservableCollection` on the beginning of the app. This `ObservableCollection` is bound to a `GridView` with an `DataTemplate`. When the app started i can see my lights with the right data. I then refetch the data to check if any lamp property has changed every 500ms. I can clearly see that the object properties are succesfully updated, but the bound data doesn't recognize this change. So the UI does not change either. I tried to use the NotifyPropertyChange in Lamp class, but that did nothing either.

After a lot of trial and error i found that the ui only changes when I add, delete or replace an object in the `ObservableCollection`, but replacing is not really a practical option for me as it causes a lot of instabillity and does not look like that is the way this problem has to be resolved.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind LampCollection}" Margin="10 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Lamp">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#555555" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" >
                        <Grid Width="300" Height="200">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Source="{x:Bind ImageUri, Mode=OneWay}" Width="80"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Name="txt"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,20" Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="status" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,20" Text="{x:Bind Status, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{x:Bind ColorLamp}"  Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Maroon"/>
                            <Slider Visibility="{x:Bind Dimmable}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" Value="{x:Bind Brightness, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Xaml code

The lamp.SetStatus function just parses the string and sets the properties Brightness and Status which are bound to the UI.

```
foreach (Lamp lamp in LampCollection) {
    string response = await GetAsync(UrlString + lamp.IDX.ToString());
    dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    if (json.status == "OK") {
        lamp.SetStatus(json.result[0].Status.ToString());
    }
}
```

C# update code

**Edit**

I tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in my lamp class as described in Microsoft's documentation. It doesn't seem to do anything however. I also tried passing in the name in the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` function but that only made my app crash.

```
class Lamp : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public uint IDX { get; internal set; }
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        public bool Status { get; internal set; }
        public string ImageUri { get; internal set; }

        public bool Dimmable { get; internal set; }
        public bool ColorLamp { get; internal set; }
        public uint Brightness { get; set; }
        public float[] Color { get; set; }

        public Lamp(uint idx, string name, string status, bool dimmable, bool colorLamp) {
            IDX = idx;
            Name = name;
            Color = new float[3];
            Dimmable = dimmable;
            ColorLamp = colorLamp;
            if (status == "Off") {
                ImageUri = "Images/lamp-off.svg";
                Status = false;
            } else {
                ImageUri = "Images/lamp-on.svg";
                Status = true;

                if(dimmable) {
                    Brightness = uint.Parse(Regex.Match(status, @"\d+").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "") {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void Switch(bool status) {
            Status = status;
            if(status) ImageUri = "Images/lamp-on.svg";
            else ImageUri = "Images/lamp-off.svg";
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
        public void SetColor(float r, float g, float b) { if (ColorLamp) { Color[0] = r; Color[1] = g; Color[2] = b; } }

        public void SetStatus(string status) {
            if (status == "Off") {
                if (Status) {
                    ImageUri = "Images/lamp-off.svg";
                    Status = false;
                    if (Dimmable) Brightness = 0;
                    Debug.WriteLine(Name + "(" + IDX + ") has turned off");
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            } else {
                if (Dimmable) {
                    uint _tmpBright = uint.Parse(Regex.Match(status, @"\d+").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                    if(!Status || Brightness != _tmpBright) {
                        ImageUri = "Images/lamp-on.svg";
                        Status = true;
                        Brightness = _tmpBright;
                        Debug.WriteLine(Name + "(" + IDX + ") has turned on or changed brighntess");
                        NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!Status) {
                        ImageUri = "Images/lamp-on.svg";
                        Status = true;
                        Debug.WriteLine(Name + "(" + IDX + ") has turned on");
                        NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection` has nothing to do here (as it only informs GridView  that item was add/moved/removed)  ... the problem is that prolly  `Lamp` doesn't  implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Show an implementation of the Lamp type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based your code snippet, you called the **NotifyPropertyChanged**() method in the SetStatus() method and the **CallerMemberName** allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method, if you do not pass any propertyName to the NotifyPropertyChanged() method, it will automatically obtain the method name which is **SetStatus**. However, there is no UI bound with SetStatus, so the UI won't update. If you want to update the UI which bound with Status and Brightness properties in this scenario, you could pass these two property names to NotifyPropertyChanged() method, for example:

```
public void SetStatus(string status)
{
    if (status == "Off")
    {
        if (Status)
        {
            ImageUri = "Assets/2.jpg";
            Status = false;
            if (Dimmable) Brightness = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine(Name + "(" + IDX + ") has turned off");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Brightness");
         }
    }
    ......
}
```

*However*, every time when you change the values of Status and Brightness properties in SetStatus() method or other methods in your Lamp class, you need to call NotifyPropertyChanged("xxx") method, it is a little complicated. You can declare a private variable and override get and set methods, in the set method, calling the NotifyPropertyChanged() method, every time set a new value to your property, it will enter the set method and then notify the UI to update. Take Status and Brightness as examples:

```
public class Lamp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool status { get; set; }
    private uint brightness { get; set; }
   
    public bool Status {
        get {
            return status;
        }
        set {
            status = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public uint Brightness
    {
        get
        {
            return brightness;
        }
        set
        {
            brightness = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    // The same behavior to the following properties
    public uint IDX { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; internal set; }

    public string ImageUri { get; internal set; }

    public bool Dimmable { get; internal set; }
    public bool ColorLamp { get; internal set; }
    
    public float[] Color { get; set; }

    public Lamp(uint idx, string name, string status, bool dimmable, bool colorLamp)
    {
        IDX = idx;
        Name = name;
        Color = new float[3];
        Dimmable = dimmable;
        ColorLamp = colorLamp;
        if (status == "Off")
        {
            ImageUri = "Assets/2.jpg";
            Status = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ImageUri = "Assets/3.jpg";
            Status = true;

            if (dimmable)
            {
                Brightness = uint.Parse(Regex.Match(status, @"\d+").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void Switch(bool status)
    {
        Status = status;
        if (status) ImageUri = "Assets/3.jpg";
        else ImageUri = "Assets/2.jpg";
    }
    public void SetColor(float r, float g, float b) { if (ColorLamp) { Color[0] = r; Color[1] = g; Color[2] = b; } }

    public void SetStatus(string status)
    {
        if (status == "Off")
        {
            if (Status)
            {
                ImageUri = "Assets/2.jpg";
                Status = false;
                if (Dimmable) Brightness = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Dimmable)
            {
                uint _tmpBright = 30;
                if (!Status || Brightness != _tmpBright)
                {
                    ImageUri = "Assets/3.jpg";
                    Status = true;
                    Brightness = _tmpBright;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Status)
                {
                    ImageUri = "Assets/3.jpg";
                    Status = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Another problem that I had was that the timer was on a diffrent thread. So that made the app crash. Now I use the dispatch timer and everything works perfectly. Thanks.